# Nginx to give HTTPS over port 10000 and Basic Auth for Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, nginx

I have a Linux NodeJS/Express app that just exposes a text file to http://example.com/secret.txt and I would like to have only accessable over HTTPS on port 10000 and Basic Auth.

The `secret.txt` is not a file on the file system. It only exists in memory.

All this is easy to set up in Nginx, so the question becomes:

## Question

Can Nginx be used to give my NodeJS/Express app HTTPS over port 10000 with Basic Auth?

Comment: Do you already have some nginx setup with your node.js app? Is `/secret.txt` is the only request that the app should respond to or there can be other requests that should to be responded without basic auth?

Comment: No, I started out having the Express app write the `secret.txt` file to a file and have Nginx serve it, which works fine on the Nginx side, but the `secret.txt` contains stats that are updates 10 times per second, so having it as a file was no-go. Yes, `/secret.txt` will be the only one. There will not be any other url's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your environment correctly, but if I am, the very basic server block would look like

```
server {
    listen 10000 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/certificate/key;

    location / {
        # how we must serve other requests? assuming we should return 404 not found
        return 404;
        # we can also use special nginx 444 code to close incoming connection immediately
    }
    location = /secret.txt {
        auth_basic "Restricted area"; # whatever you want message
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/your/passwords/file;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<your_nodejs_app_port>;
    }
}
```

It should be quite obvious that the node.js app port should not be exposed to the internet and should be accessible only locally via `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.